# I cannot find .minecraft folder to install mods

Tags: minecraft

I'm kinda new on this, and need some help.
I had MC on my windows with mods, when changing to Ubuntu I got the same version. I tried to install the mods I had on my windows but I cannot make it work, because there's no .minecraft file nor %appdata%. I followed instructions like copying modloader into the .jar file, which didn't work and other stuff 
Can you help me, please?

Comment: Follow the directions below but also when installing mods, either follow a Linux directions list or Mac directions, the process for both Mac and Linux are relatively the same.

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu shows folders a bit differently, and organizes them in a different fashion.

Open your home folder. Press Ctrl+H. You should now see it as "dot-folders" are usually hidden. This assumes you have run minecraft as your user previously. If you haven't, run it, doing a few things in it(just to get it to create its config files).

Comment: I've done it, and I found one, but the Windows one (I've got all the files for Windows, MAC and Ubuntu) the .jar inside is the same as the one I run for playing normally. I just tried pasting the mods in it, modifying it, and it doesn't run. Running the other file, runs with no mods. D: I must be doing something wrong...

Comment: I don't really work with Minecraft, but I'll ask some acquaintances about this.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to access it.

Open up Minecraft. If you haven't logged in yet, then do so, the at a corner of the window press the button that says "Edit Profile".

Then there's a button at the bottom that says "Open Game Dir" which will open the .minecraft folder you're looking for.

That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

.minecraft/mods and when you go to load it make sure you select the "forge" profile to access the mods in game!!

Answer (score 0):

When you've installed it using `snap install`, try looking inside `~/snap/minecraft-launcher-ot/67/.minecraft` Another way to find it on any operating system is by starting the game (so you come at the menu with "Singleplayer" and "Multiplayer" on it), pressing options >> Resource Packs... >> Open Resource Pack Folder and then going one folder level higher.

Answer (score -1):

it actually is not called %APPDATA% It is actually called mods if you installed forge to access it you go to resource packs and open the file to put them in but then you go back a file (you will see it in the corner of the window) it is called .minecraft look in there AFTER you installed forge it will be there!;)